# how to use QTimer without a QT application

Tags: c++, qt, timer

i want to use the QTimer in my regular class (no QT Application but derived from QTimer). but when i try this:

Header:

```
#include <qtimer.h>
QTimer* m_timer;
public slots:
    void UpdateClock();
```

Source:

```
    m_timer = new QTimer(this);
    QObject::connect(m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(UpdateClock()));
    m_timer->start(1000);

void MyClass::UpdateClock()
{
    int i = 0;
}
```

the timer never jumps into the UpdateClock method! Do you know why and how i solve that problem??

Thanks!

Comment: if your application is kinda event based then link with qt and follow suggestions given by the answer. Otherwise, why not just use `sleep()`

Answer (score 5):

QTimer depends on QCoreApplication. If you don't start a QCoreApplication, nothing will activate the QTimer. (QApplication inherits QCoreApplication and is usually used.)

Comment: oh thats bad, bc i don´t have a GUI. so how can i get a(ny) timer though?

Comment: QCoreApplication. GUI applications use QApplication, QCoreApplication is for you.

Comment: well my test application (which instantiates my class) is a QApplication but my class, which should use/control the timer not. so how can i still use the timer?

Comment: Use a QCoreApplication.

Comment: but how do i use it? I don´t have a main function in my class

Comment: You can create it in any function and call its exec() member. That starts an event loop, which delivers your timer events. When someone stops the event loop using QCoreApplication::quit(), exec() returns. If this does not fit into your design, then I suggest that you look for something other than a QTimer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use signals and slots in Qt, you need an **event loop** to process the signals and dispatch them.

Usually, in main.cpp you have something like:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    ...
    return app.exec(); // the event loop is started and runs here
}
```

If there is no need for a GUI, you can use

```
QCoreApplication
```

You can also create your own event loop using:

```
QEventLoop
```

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qeventloop.html
and process only the QTimer event. However, you will still need to create a QApplication.

Comment: thanks, but i don´t have a main method, so how can I use it within my class? well i have a main method, but just in the TestApplication and I want the timer to be inside my class.

Comment: Just use QCoreApplication in your main method in the TestApplication, or where the main.cpp is. You can use the QTime anywhere in your code afterwards :-)

Comment: well my TestApplication is a QApplication which uses my class via an Interface. Inside the TestApplication project i can easily use the time, but when i want to create a time in my class, it doesn´t call the Update method :(